# Install Windows 10 via PXE

Tags: windows-10, installation, pxe, unattended

I've been searching for a way to complete an unattended Windows 10 installation with only bad luck.  I have found lots of information on loading and running 10 from a PXE server but nothing saying it is or isn't possible to run what I'm describing here.  Is there a way to do this that is supported by Windows or can be at least run by a Windows machine?

Comment: So just to confirm you are looking to confirm it’s possible to install Windows through PXE?  [It is indeed possible](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-windows-cm/deploy-windows-10-using-pxe-and-configuration-manager#:~:text=%20Procedures%20%201%20Start%20the%20PC0001%20computer.,the%20Edit%20Task%20Sequence%20Variables%20page%2C...%20More%20)

Comment: That's right. Not just boot Windows but install it to a drive so it can boot independently in the future.

Comment: I have seen that article and was apprehensive due to it mentioning Windows 10 Enterprise in the first few lines.  I am not installing Enterprise edition but rather Pro.

Comment: Any answers to that concern?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Serva (automated PXE server).

[https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/WindowsPXE1.html)

[https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE2.html#unattended](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/WindowsPXE2.html#unattended)

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft supported way is to run Windows Server and WDS.

All versions and editions of Windows can be installed this way, most even supported by Microsoft, and often used in PC manufacture.

I would use [iPXEs wimboot](https://ipxe.org/wimboot)
You can find [a guide on how to run winpe](https://ipxe.org/howto/winpe)

The basic steps is to start the normal setup environment, which requires `boot.wim` from the installation media. Then before starting the actual setup, open cmd (Shfit+F10) and mount the installation share with `net use ...` and then run the setup from that share.

If the PXE setup itself is the issue, and you only want to run Windows software then we are back to Server again, An intersting read even if you are not using iPXE is [this MS DHCP howto](https://ipxe.org/howto/msdhcp)

You also mention running Windows directly, then iSCSI over PXE is possible, but that has the possibility of getting you in to a deep hole, just say that it is possible, but maybe not worth it.

Comment: WDS with MDT(or SCCM)